# Only accept quarterly floats

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like an HTML input validated on integer # (hourly), #.5 (half hourly) and #.25 (quarter).

I tried using HTML input `type='number'`, but this seems to be fixed integers only. Does anybody have any clue on how to make a system that restricts on quarters?

Answer (score 4):

Guessing you haven't tried step attribute yet?

Also believe you want it to be a time input since you mention hourly

```css
:invalid{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<input type="time" step="900"><br>
<input type="number" step="0.25">
```